# Penalize or reward answers based on question score?

Tags: feature-request

Today, when I logged into Stack Overflow, I saw a string of questions that had answers, all of which had negative scores. It seems that giving answers to negative questions violates the core idea of the site, which is to encourage asking good questions.

I looked over some of my history and I have been guilty of this myself - so I got to thinking that you could discourage this behavior by applying some kind of penalty to the points earned by answer upvotes and accepts on negatively scored questions. If, for instance, you only earned 50% for answers you submit on negatively scored questions, that could be an incentive not to answer those questions.

*For me, looking at my historical answers, the reason I was answering things that didn't fit on the site - negative score questions, requests for tools and things like that - seems to be that I was in "Fastest Gun in the West" mode, trying to build rep. I'm not proud of it.*

Possible challenges include:

- If a question is borderline (say, at 0), with many votes up and down, then someone might put an answer that later becomes worth less points because a single downvote drops it from 0 to -1. This might be something you could handle by requiring a set proportion of downvotes, or by triggering the penalty at -2 or something similar.
- Over time, you could end up having to re-adjust the score if someone's question moves up or down after the fact. This would create a lot of rep changes, which could be confusing. One possible solution would be to award the points for the state of the question when your answer was submitted. But this could seem capricious and arbitrary, and would result in on-going upvotes to answers submitted before a question went negative getting the regular point score. In a way, this might encourage, rather than discourage, quickly answering questions.

Rather then penalizing answers on negative questions, perhaps a better approach could be rewarding answers on positive questions. Perhaps each upvote on a question could adjust the points awarded for an answer by a set percentage (arbitrarily throwing out a number here, 2%). So, if you answer a question that's got 5 upvotes, you get 1.1x the number of points you would normally get for your answers. This would be less punitive, but would still provide an incentive to answer questions with higher vote totals.

A way around the other issues (of borderline questions and changing question score over time) could be to only award the modifier points once the asker accepts an answer. Since most negatively-scored questions probably won't be answered (I'm making a WAG here, but I could be wrong), this would limit us to using the positive version. Basically, the way it would work would be:

- Asker posts their question, which attracts a certain number of upvotes.
- Several people post answers, which are upvoted or downvoted based on the quality. Normal amounts of points are awarded for each.
- When the asker accepts one of the answers, the number of upvotes on their question is "locked in" for the purpose of calculating the bonus. All answers get a bonus based on the upvotes for the question (using whatever makes sense, be it 1% or 2% or whatever).
- Future upvotes, downvotes, and new answers do not receive any bonuses.
- Removing the acceptance and giving it to someone else does not "reset" the bonuses. They are awarded only on the first accept.

*I'm not as familiar with Meta as I am with regular SO, so I may be tagging this wrong - if so, please mod or edit as appropriate. Thanks.*

Answer (score 15):

SO isn't even willing to punish answerers who answer only blatant duplicates, so why do you think it would punish them for answering merely bad questions and not duplicates?

Snark and salt aside, this would not have a good outcome.  Think about what your proposal would encourage:

- Upvoting questions you answer to make your answer count more
- Not downvoting questions you answer to make your answer count more
- Hounding OP for acceptance even more than already

What it would fail to do:

- Persuade people to answer more good questions. Good (and accepted) answers to good questions already get tons of upvotes, and the people answering them get tons of rep from it.
- Dissuade people from answering bad questions. People answer bad questions (as you pointed out already) to gather reputation, or because they have a great answer for that kind of question in mind.

Further considerations:

- A lot of times, bad questions can be salvaged by great answers. We even have a badge to encourage this (the ["Reversal" badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) — Provide an answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score).

Comment: One reason that comes to mind is it is immediately obvious what a bad question is, but may not be obvious that a question is a duplicate. I know the tags I follow pretty well, and am pretty good at searching, so I can usually find duplicates quickly. But not everyone has those skills, so they might answer in the meantime. (True on all other counts, though.)

Comment: @CodyGray The first paragraph was me snarking salt at a specific SE employee, I should probably remove it :/

Comment: *SO isn't even willing to punish answerers who answer only blatant duplicates.* That may be true, but they do not stop us from downvoting them.

Comment: I didn't think about the feedback look between those who answer and those who upvote / downvote. :/

Comment: The reversal-badge isn't really a poster-child of a successful badge. While there are *some* gems getting it, there are also lots of the worst questions with an answer which, while correct and pointing out the OP's error, aren't actually useful.

Comment: I suppose it might encourage one positive outcome, editing the question to make it less bad.  But we already have a badge series for that (Explainer).

Comment: Is it normal to accept an answer on these type of feature request questions? I'm not familiar with the standards. :)