# Should people who downvote answers based on the question's quality be reprimanded?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43901193/5386374) question.  Now, it isn't exactly the best of questions, but multiple people (including myself) were kind enough to answer, and explain to the OP how their code works<sup>1</sup>.  Due to this, however, I noticed something: In the time since the question was posted, every single answer has been downvoted, including the correct ones.

In short, it appears that we [*still*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions) have a problem of people downvoting answers based on the question's quality, instead of the answers' quality.  Considering that this is implied to be a violation of site policy<sup>2</sup>, and that it's *very* clearly an attempt to exploit a loophole in the Roomba<sup>3</sup>, **should anyone who is found to do this be reprimanded**?

Related:

- [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions)
- [Downvoting good answers on bad questions, helpful or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274919/downvoting-good-answers-on-bad-questions-helpful-or-not)
- [Punish answerers of bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252656/punish-answerers-of-bad-questions)
- [Penalize or reward answers based on question score?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316980/penalize-or-reward-answers-based-on-question-score)

[Note that this question is *not* about whether it's okay to do so, which it very clearly is **NOT**.  Rather, it is solely about whether action should be taken against people who do so, which is a topic that related questions don't appear to cover.]
[Note that the answers to the example question provided may or may not actually be a victim of this behaviour; I lack the necessary tools to determine whether it is or isn't the case (and, [as pointed out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349077/should-people-who-downvote-answers-based-on-the-questions-quality-be-reprimande?noredirect=1#comment472390_349077), even with tools there would still be uncertainty as to the motive behind the voting, as all they would provide is circumstantial evidence), but find the presence of exactly one downvote on each answer (as of the time I posted this) suspicious.]

---

<sup>1: Personally, I answered because the comments in the OP's code indicate that they were trying to figure out how it works, and on the right track, but just needed a bit of help wrapping their head around it.  The code itself is an entirely valid function (assuming the ever-present-among-newbies `using namespace std;` is in effect), of the sort that would be present in a tutorial on how to use pointers; it was likely the answer to a homework question, but they didn't understand how it worked.  Basically, I answered because they indicated that they actually wanted to *understand* the code, and not be just one of the help vampires that copy-pastes code beyond their comprehending.

2: The [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) badge is awarded for supplying good answers to bad questions, implying that site policy supports answering bad questions, as long as the answer is well thought out.  This is likely intended to ensure that even bad questions have a duplicate source, but I can't say for certain.  [It doesn't always work out this way, however, and there have been mentions of correct-but-useless answers getting the badge.]  Similarly, [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) suggests that good answers are the site's most useful resource, which contradicts the "downvote all answers on bad questions, whether they're good or bad" mentality.

3: To my knowledge, the Roomba simply checks whether the question and answers are all downvoted to decide whether to delete the question, and doesn't take any other data into consideration, not even things such as whether all answers were downvoted by the same user, or whether they were downvoted at roughly the same time.  This leaves it vulnerable to exploitation by robo-downvoters.</sup>

Comment: How would find out what people base their votes on?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I can't; while tools would be able to provide circumstantial evidence (namely, if all downvotes are by the same person, and/or came within seconds of each other, it may indicate that something is up), they wouldn't be able to explicitly prove this to be the case.  I merely find the presence of exactly one downvote on each answer to be suspicious.

Comment: @yellowantphil If they upvote all bad posts on a single question, just because the question itself is good, then perhaps.  If people decide that users who downvote answers based on the question's quality should be reprimanded, then the obvious corollary question would be whether people who upvote answers based on the question's quality should be reprimanded as well.

Comment: I'd file this under "it's a bummer an attempt at helping someone with a maybe basic, but not completely idiotic/lazy question got downvoted" and move on. There is no solution to this that wouldn't cripple the system in some way and have awful unintended consequences. Catching the occasional downvote is the price one pays when answering borderline/unpopular questions; as long as you're sure the questions are really worth it, it's arguably a price worth paying and an upstanding stance to take.

Comment: @Pekka웃 The problem isn't with voting on this question's answers in particular (I merely used it because it's the question that prompted this concern), but that generally speaking, downvoting good answers if the question itself is bad has the potential to get the answers swallowed by the Roomba, if enough people do it.  I don't want that to happen.

Comment: To follow up on @yellowantphil's question, I frankly don't care all that much about discouraging or disheartening those who answer lousy questions. I can see the arguments for why downvoting answers to questions that are merely *downvote*-worthy is not really the best idea, but I just don't think it's worth making a big deal about at this point. But, of course, upvotes to bad posts happen a lot, and are honestly much more of a threat, being a similar distortion of the roomba and inflating rep, which in turns distorts *the entire basis of community moderation*.

Comment: Of course, upvoting bad posts, whether to balance out their score or for other reasons, is widely condemned, but nothing else is being done about it. But I'm not even sure we need to match this — that is, focus on publicizing condemnation of downvoting answers to downvoted questions — when we've got so many far more important voting quality problems to work on.

Comment: So, you argue that the "Reversal" Badge is an indicator for encouraging answers even on lower quality question, yet the help center says something else: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ("Answer well-asked questions").

Comment: 'Now, it isn't exactly the best of questions' well, that's one way of putting it.  It's obviously an academic exercise, now cleanly completed by SO homework drones:(

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad

Comment: I mean... said users are already charged some rep for doing so. What else would you want done?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit From the look of it, he already had the answer to his homework question, but just didn't know _why_ it was the answer.  His desire to understand that is why I answered, personally.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Think the corollary question of "Should people who upvote answers based on the question's quality be reprimanded?" should be asked, then?

Comment: @Tom It says not to answer questions which: 1) "are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem", 2) "solicit opinions rather than facts", 3) "have already been asked and answered many times before", 4) "require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions", or 5) "are not about programming as defined in the help center".  Not every bad question fits in these categories.

Comment: @KevinB Hmm... not sure, actually, now that you mention it.  It was just an idea that popped into my head, due to seeing it happen a few times and seeing it mentioned on meta a few times.

Comment: @Ðаn See the Meta discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad) on whether that's official site policy or just a suggestion.

Comment: Then answer the questions which aren't covered in that paragraph and see what happens.

Answer (score 21):

> should anyone who is found to do this be reprimanded?

And what sort of "reprimand" would you suggest? There's no automatic system that could determine whether those downvotes were actually merited. So this would be (yet another) thing moderators would have to deal with.

This is not a problem worth solving. After all, the very example you provided was closed, which is a strong indicator that it shouldn't have been answered at all.

> The Reversal badge is awarded for supplying good answers to bad questions, implying that site policy supports answering bad questions, as long as the answer is well thought out. This is likely intended to ensure that even bad questions have a duplicate source, but I can't say for certain. [It doesn't always work out this way, however, and there have been mentions of correct-but-useless answers getting the badge.] Similarly, this blog post suggests that good answers are the site's most useful resource, which contradicts the "downvote all answers on bad questions, whether they're good or bad" mentality.

That's like saying that the Tumbleweed badge implies that we want people to ask questions that don't get noticed. Reversal is a badge that notes that something unusual has happened; it is *not* intended to be an encouragement of behavior.

And you'll note that it has only been awarded *[273 times](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal).* It is one of the rarest gold badges.

> To my knowledge, the Roomba simply checks whether the question and answers are all downvoted to decide whether to delete the question, and doesn't take any other data into consideration, not even things such as whether all answers were downvoted by the same user, or whether they were downvoted at roughly the same time. This leaves it vulnerable to exploitation by robo-downvoters.

Nonsense. If you look at the actual answers to the [Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions), you'll see that the second answer (which is highly upvoted) explains that some people.

People who downvote in the manner you suggest are merely trying to punish users in some small way for doing what they feel is detrimental to the site: answering bad questions, thus encouraging the asking of more bad questions. Whether you agree with that reasoning or not, it has nothing to do with gaming the Roomba.

Comment: speaking of Reversal badge, 100+ upvotes to [idea for it to go away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277576/839601) suggest that it indeed tends to encourage slippery attitude among answerers

Comment: You make some good points, but since I joined the site, I _have_ seen one or two comments on meta about people downvoting answers to bad questions _specifically_ so they fall beneath the Roomba threshold.  That's why I suspect triggering the Roomba to be the underlying motive to anyone who wants to "punish" people for answering bad questions, regardless of whether their answer itself is good.

Comment: @JustinTime So because one or two comments were made on it then obviously every downvote on every bad question is insidiously attempting to trigger the roomba on a bad question, and couldn't possibly because the answer is just bad, or not useful.

Comment: @Servy How did you get "good question with bad answer" out of "bad question with good answer"?

Comment: @JustinTime Sorry, I meant to say bad question both times, not just the first.

Comment: @Servy That makes a bit more sense, but I still don't see how you got "bad answer" out of it.  Unless you're one of the people that thinks that any answer on a bad question is automatically bad itself, regardless of the answer's quality.

Comment: Either way, these attempts to punish users for actually answering bad questions expressly violates site policy regarding answers vs. questions, as described in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/); specifically, the site policy is that obtaining good answers is the express purpose of the site, and that people shouldn't be punished for providing good answers.  Thus, anyone who judges an answer solely on the question's quality is violating this policy, as they show that they don't care how good or bad the answer is, they just want it gone.

Comment: @JustinTime The overwhelming majority of answers to bad questions are going to be bad.  **That's what makes questions bad**.  Bad questions are *defined* as questions that either cannot be answered with a quality answers, or questions that overwhelmingly tend to attract bad answers.  As such, for basically every bad question you see, the answers are almost always going to be bad answers.  You should be pretty shocked to see a really great answer to a bad question, so seeing lots of downvotes on answers to bad questions is *the expected outcome* because those answers are almost certainly bad.

Comment: @JustinTime You, on the other hand, are making the assumption that the majority of answers to bad questions are good answers, and are thus assuming that all of the downvotes that these answers are attracting are people who didn't even read them and just downvoted them.  This is simply a false assumption.  The problems with bad questions mean that writing a good answer for it is either impossible, or *almost* impossible, and so odds are the people that are evaluating them are going to realize that they're bad, because they *really are*.  That's why we don't want bad questions.

Comment: @Servy So, first you say that "a bad question is bad because its answers are bad" (which completely ignores the question's quality), and then you say that "the answers are bad because the question is bad" (which completely ignores the answer's quality).  Either way, you assume that all answers on bad questions are themselves bad, regardless of the answer's quality.

Comment: @Servy You also _completely_ misunderstand my intent, and try to put false claims in my mouth.  I'm _solely_ concerned with the case where 1) a bad question receives a good answer, and 2) that answer is then downvoted because the question is bad.  This is an uncommon case, but I'm ignoring all other cases because _they aren't relevant to this discussion_.  And no, "being an answer to a bad question" doesn't automatically make an answer bad, no matter what you may think; every answer and every question must be judged _solely_ on its own quality, not on the quality of any related posts.

Comment: @JustinTime: I think part of the problem is your definition of "good answer". I don't see any good answers on the closed question you referred us to. Oh, those answers aren't necessarily *bad*, but just because something isn't bad doesn't automatically make it good. Those answers are mediocre or so-so. Furthermore, good answers on bad questions are had to find, since bad questions are less likely to be found via search (the titles are usually terrible and so forth). So whatever good they may be isn't being utilized by anyone besides the OP.

Comment: @JustinTime I never said the first thing.  I said bad questions are bad because answers to it *will* be bad; they *cannot* (or are highly unlikely to be) be good.  Thus saying that bad answers can sometimes be a result of problems with the question is entirely consistent with that.  If bad questions were consistently creating quality answers *they wouldn't be bad questions*.  Bad questions are **defined** as being questions where the answers can't, or won't, be good.

Comment: @JustinTime So you're talking about a situation that basically *never* happens (because bad questions virtually never attract good answers, and in the *very rare* instance where they do, they pretty much never have a problem of getting lots of downvotes) and are therefore attempting to implement a change (that is inherently impossible, because you can never know why someone is voting) that is going to actually change nothing at all.

Comment: @JustinTime Again, you seem to be repeatedly under the assumption that people are voting with answers and not even reading them, or even taking a moment to *consider* their quality.  I see no evidence at all that that's the case.  The issue is that *the quality of a question directly affects the quality of an answer*.  There are *lots* of answer that are bad answers, and the reasons that they're bad are directly related to problems in the question.  Downvoting such an answer *is still judging the answer based on it quality*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Perhaps.  I define good answers as ones that are 1) correct, 2) as descriptive as necessary to explain itself, and 3) useful to anyone with the same problem as described in the question; the question's quality is irrelevant, as good questions can receive bad answers and bad questions can receive good answers.

Comment: @Servy " I said bad questions are bad because answers to it will be bad; they cannot (or are highly unlikely to be) be good."  So, you claim that 1) the answers' quality decides the question's quality, regardless of the quality (or lack thereof) the question itself has if it exists in a void, without any answers, and 2) As a result of #1, all answers to bad questions are themselves bad.  Are you familiar with the term ["circular reasoning"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning)?

Comment: No offense, but your argument basically boils down to "the answers are bad because the question is bad, and the question is bad because the answers are bad".  It also implies that you downvote or upvote answers based on the quality of the question, and ignore the quality of the answer itself; your claim that "the quality of a question directly affects the quality of an answer" supports this, as you outright admitted that you consider the question's quality to be a major factor in the answer's quality.

Comment: @JustinTime: His point is that the questions we close are closed because they have historically been found to, more often than not, produce noise rather than good information. While it is *possible* that an unclear question will produce good information, the signal-to-noise ratio of such questions is too low to bother with. And even if it did produce good information, if the question is unclear... how could you *judge* the answer? You don't really know what the question is asking.

Comment: @NicolBolas He should've actually said that, then, instead of trying to claim that all answers to bad questions are automatically bad _because_ they answer bad questions.  And if the question is unclear, then the answer is liable to fail the "correct" part of my assessment, which would make it count as bad in my opinion unless the usefulness and descriptiveness are enough to compensate for the incorrectness (where it probably won't be all that useful, leaving it to fall on descriptiveness, which won't really be enough to outweigh incorrectness solely by itself).

Comment: I would make an exception if the answer is _extremely_ useful to programmers in general, and be more lenient if it would be useful in situations similar to the one vaguely described in the question.

Comment: @JustinTime No, I *didn't* say that bad answers make a question bad.  You falsely claimed that I said as much before, and I corrected  you then; not sure why you're still claiming I've said as much.  Yes, I've most certainly said that the quality of a question directly affects the quality of answers.  What makes you think it doesn't?  The quality of a question has a *huge* effect on the quality of answers.  Considering you're describing yourself in a later comment how a question's quality can affect an answer, you appear to believe it does yourself.

Comment: @Ðаn Yes, unclear questions are a case where providing good, correct answers is problematic, because the answerer is often forced to guess at what the OP wants; not all bad questions are unclear, though, and ones that are bad for other reasons can more easily have good answers.  And yes, I'm familiar with the rudeness issue, and consider the particular case I wanted to discuss (users downvoting answers because the question is bad) to be a part of it.

Comment: @Servy You said that, ["The overwhelming majority of answers to bad questions are going to be bad. **That's what makes questions bad.** Bad questions are _defined_ as questions that either cannot be answered with a quality answers, or questions that overwhelmingly tend to attract bad answers."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349077/should-people-who-downvote-answers-based-on-the-questions-quality-be-reprimande/349081?noredirect=1#comment472580_349081)

Comment: This asserts that if the question is bad, then the answers will be bad as well.  It then asserts that the question is bad _because_ the answers will be bad.  Put together, it says that the answers will be bad if the question is bad, but the question is bad if the answers are bad; this is, as I said, circular reasoning, in that it claims that the answers are bad because the question is bad, and the question is bad because the answers are bad.  Unless you meant for it to be interpreted some other way, in which case I'd like to know what you actually meant.

Comment: You also said, in the same comment, that, "You should be pretty shocked to see a really great answer to a bad question, so seeing lots of downvotes on answers to bad questions is _the expected outcome_ because those answers are almost certainly bad."  Again, you assume that the answers are bad because the question is bad, with the implication that you don't even need to read the answers to assess their quality.

Comment: This attitude, where one assumes the quality of the answers from the quality of the questions, can very easily lead to the behaviour I was talking about (downvoting good answers on bad questions because the questions themselves are bad).  I personally consider it very unhelpful, because a bad question with a good answer could very easily be used as a duplicate source for other bad questions, considering that a majority of them stem from new programmers either not knowing what to search for, or not knowing how the other question's situation matches up with theirs.

Comment: @JustinTime Yes, I said that a bad question is *defined* as a question that attracts bad answers.  I never said that a question having bad answers makes the question bad (because it's not true, you can provide bad answers to *great* questions).  So no, my argument isn't circular at all.  "You assume that the answers are bad because the question is bad, with the implication that you don't even need to read the answers to assess their quality." I didn't state that at all.  Again, you're arguing a straw man.  Saying that answers to a bad question are usually bad doesn't make that assumption true.

Comment: @Servy Again, I quote, "Bad questions are defined as questions that either cannot be answered with a quality answers, or questions that overwhelmingly tend to attract bad answers."  How do you expect this to be interpreted, other than claiming that the question is bad _because_ the answers to it are bad?

Comment: @JustinTime You're making an entirely false and baseless assumption in stating that other people are making false assumptions about answers.  These answers *are bad answers*.  They're not good answers.  They're getting downvotes *because they're bad answers*, not because people didn't read them and didn't realize that they're good answers.

Comment: @Servy So, on what grounds do you consider correct, descriptive answers, which are useful to anyone else with the same question, to be bad, then?  Because, as I already said _multiple_ times, I'm solely concerned with the case where bad questions receive good answers, not with the cases where bad questions receive bad answers.  Or do you just define good answers some other way?

Comment: @JustinTime "Sugar water attracts bees, therefore literally anywhere I see bees must have sugar water nearby"  That's equivalent to your line of argument.  Just because a bad question is going to attract bad answers, and more or less can't attract good answers, doesn't mean that any question with bad answers is bad. Again, a good question can still have bad answers. Your logic is entirely flawed. A *valid* conclusion from my assumption would be to say if a question has great answers, it's almost certainly a good question, or put another way, a good question is one that *can have good answers*.

Comment: @JustinTime There are *lots* of things that can make an answer with no factual inaccuracies a bad answer.  It might not answer the question, it might be off topic, it might be unclear, it might be using poor practices, it might have security vulnerabilities, it might be duplicating other content, it might not be sufficiently well explained, it might be incomplete, it might be an opinion not based in fact, it might be spam, etc.

Comment: @Servy No one said good questions can't have bad answers.  I merely pointed out the flaws in your statements: You claim that a question is bad because it cannot have good answers, yet also claim that the answers to a bad question are "almost certainly bad" because the question itself is bad.  How do you expect these two statements _not_ to be interpreted as circular logic?

Comment: Put together, they assert that the answer is bad because the question is bad, and that the question is bad because all answers to it will be bad (where, again, the answers are considered bad because the question is bad).

Comment: OK, *both of you*, take this to chat.

Comment: @JustinTime *You* asserted that I said that good questions can't have bad answers, despite me never making such a claim, and you used that false claim to assert that my logic is circular.  Here's a simpler analogy for you.  I'm defining a "good" box as a box that is large enough for me to fit my toaster in it.  If I can't fit my toaster in a box, that box isn't good.  Is that circular logic (hint, no, it's not).

Comment: @JustinTime Again, you *continue* to say that I've asserted that a question is bad *because* it has bad answers, and I have *continued* to tell you that that is not true, and I have never asserted as much.  *You* are putting forth an invalid assertion, claiming I'm asserting it, and then claiming my logic is flawed because of it.  I'm not asserting that.

Comment: @Servy Also: If an answer doesn't answer the question, it's clearly not correct.  If it's off-topic, it's not useful.  If it's unclear, it might be incorrect, useless, or not descriptive.  If it's an intentional duplicate, then it's not useful because it merely rehashes already-known information without adding to it.  If it's not well explained, then it's clearly not descriptive.  If it's incomplete, it's probably not correct (although it may be useful, in which case it's mediocre).  If it's opinion, it's probably not correct, and may not be useful.  If it's spam, it fails all 3 requirements.

Comment: @NicolBolas I tried, but I got an error message when I clicked the "automatically move this discussion to chat" link.  Is there another way to move it to a chat room?

Comment: @Servy Of the possible "bad" answers you listed, the ones that use poor practices and the ones that have vulnerabilities would be a grey area, IMO.  They clearly won't be great, but could still be good in their own right if they're sufficiently informative (especially if they point out said poor practices and/or vulnerabilities, then explain why that particular method was used).

Comment: @JustinTime So, given those factors, presumably you can now see how a bad question isn't going to attract good answers.  If the question is unclear, you can't assert that an answer answers it, so it isn't correct, if it's off topic, then it's also not a good answer, if it's a common duplicate, again, the answer is duplicating information, if it's too broad the answer is pretty much *going* to be incomplete, by necessity, if it's asking for opinions, then answers are going to be giving opinions.  If a question is able to attract answers with none of these problems *it's not a bad question*.

Comment: And as I said, I based my assertions on a direct reading of your own words.  Again, and I quote, "The overwhelming majority of answers to bad questions are going to be bad. That's what makes questions bad. Bad questions are defined as questions that either cannot be answered with a quality answers, or questions that overwhelmingly tend to attract bad answers." and "You should be pretty shocked to see a really great answer to a bad question, so seeing lots of downvotes on answers to bad questions is the expected outcome because those answers are almost certainly bad."

Comment: How else do you want me to interpret _your own words_?

Comment: @JustinTime You keep quoting me, and I still stand by that quote.  *That quote doesn't assert what you claim it does*.  The fact that bad questions are *defined* as questions that can only be answered with bad answers *doesn't* meant that bad answers make the question bad.  *You're reversing the causality* and that's not valid.  Bad answers don't make a question bad, a bad question *cannot attract good answers*, but a good question can still attract bad answers, so bad answers don't make a question bad, even though bad questions *do* mean that an answer can't be good.

Comment: @Servy Again, you assume that every answer to a bad question will fall into at least one of those categories.  This is the entire point I'm making: _You assume the answer is bad, because it's posted in reply to a question that's bad._  To put it simply, that's not true: If a question is bad, but clear enough to receive a good answer, the most likely case is that any good answer will be an unintentional duplicate; if the answerer knew about the duplicated information, they would likely flag the question as a duplicate and move on.

Comment: @JustinTime Well, I did state that my list of problems wasn't a definitive list, but yes, any bad question is going to have answers that have *some* major problem.  This isn't an assumption, rather, *it's true by definition*.  If a question is able to attract answers that don't have those, or any other, problems *then the question isn't a bad question*.  That a bad question is very unlikely to attract good answers *is tautological*, not an assumption.

Comment: Also, in regards to the quotes, I think you missed the point I was trying to make.  The first quote asserts that you define a bad question as a question which will only receive bad answers.  The second quote asserts that the answers posted on bad questions are themselves "almost certainly bad".  By themselves, each quote is fine, and a valid view on bad questions & bad answers.  However, the circular logic comes up when they're _combined_.  The question is bad because it will only receive bad answers, but the answers are almost certainly bad because the question itself is bad.

Comment: @JustinTime If an answer is just duplicating lots of readily accessible good information that's a problem, and it's a problem regardless of whether or not he author realizes it.  The intent of the author doesn't matter here.  It's simply not useful to duplicate information (without improving on it somehow), even if unintentional.

Comment: @JustinTime If I *defined* a bad answer as an answer to a bad question, then yes, it would be circular logic.  I've done no such thing.  A *definition* of what makes a bad answer would be [something like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349077/should-people-who-downvote-answers-based-on-the-questions-quality-be-reprimande/349081?noredirect=1#comment474871_349081) although, again, that's not a complete definition, just a starting point.  Bad answers are answers with problems like that, bad questions are questions that can't attract answers without problems like that.

Comment: @Servy Okay, as a thought experiment, what flaws, if any, do you see in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15960054/5386374)?  The question itself is bad (it's an extremely simple question, which the OP only asked because they didn't take the time to test one line of code themself); the answer, however, is not only very thorough (it shows both possibilities), but also provides an introductory explanation of how the more complex answer works (by showing both that the `boolalpha` representation is tied to locale, and specifically how a locale determines said representation).

Comment: @Servy Ah, okay, now I see where you're coming from.  I read it as you claiming that you considered "answer to a bad question" to be one of the definitions of a bad answer.  My mistake, then.

Comment: (Personally, the only flaw I see in the answer I linked is the one mentioned in the comment: It explains `boolalpha`, but neither explains nor demonstrates its counterpart `noboolalpha`.)

Comment: @Servy I'll assume from your silence that you didn't see any flaws in the answer I linked.  Considering its quality, and the question's lack thereof, it disproves the claim that a bad question is a question which will only receive bad answers.

Comment: @JustinTime It's outside of my area of expertise, so I can't really comment on it's quality.  You say that the question isn't a good question because you can answer it by just running the code, if that's true then that means that all of the information in the answer is simply irrelevant, because you don't need to know any of it in order to answer the question, and it's all just off topic information.  So if you're assessment of the question is correct then the answer *could* be a useful answer if it's actually posted to a question for which the information would be on topic.